# Convert JSON response to a dictionary

Tags: python, json

I got the following response from an a request (respone below is sliced). However, when I try to convert the response to a dictionary it throws back an error. What is wrong with "response"?

```
response= b'\xef\xbb\xbf<message:MessageGroup xmlns="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/generic" xmlns:common="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/common" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/generic http://www.sdmx.org/docs/2_0/SDMXGenericData.xsd http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/message ht'

json.loads(str(response))
```

[image]

Comment: Because `response` is not a JSON at all?

Comment: the json api doesn't perform magic.  It converts a json serialized text into a dictionary.  Your response is a byte string

Comment: In fact it's a byte string that contains XML, not JSON

Comment: It's probably not JSON. This is SDMXML(XML) [Here's more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60024557/python-parse-xml-files-from-eurostat-sdmx)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python parse xml files from eurostat sdmx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60024557/python-parse-xml-files-from-eurostat-sdmx)

Answer (score 1):

you have to decode your response

try this:

import codecs

decoded_data=codecs.decode(response, 'utf-8-sig')

print(decoded_data)

you can read the article : https://www.howtosolutions.net/2019/04/python-fixing-unexpected-utf-8-bom-error-when-loading-json-data/

hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

This solved it.

```
import xmltodict

response= b'\xef\xbb\xbf<message:MessageGroup xmlns="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/generic" xmlns:common="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/common" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/generic http://www.sdmx.org/docs/2_0/SDMXGenericData.xsd http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/message ht'

xmltodict.parse(response)
```